# How much money could we get with a reverse mortgage?

Tags: retirement, reverse-mortgages

My wife (67) and I (72) are retired with an income of $70k/year and a savings of $30k. We have a loan of $300k with a mortgage payment of $1,786/month on a single family home valued at $600k. We spend all of our income so we are looking to convert our equity into cash to improve our quality of life.

One of the choices is to downsize.  The other is a reverse mortgage.

Can anyone tell me what range of monthly income we would qualify for and how long that would last?

I understand that we are responsible for taxes and insurance and have to maintain the home as our principal residence.

Comment: It depends on interest rates. Your bank should be able to give you the information your question asks for.

Comment: i would be happy using an estimate of todays rates.

Comment: Do you understand how horrible a deal reverse mortgages are?  Essentially you will be giving away about 1/3 of your equity.

Comment: If you want to know how much monthly income you can obtain from a reverse mortgage, contact the agencies that offer them.  They will happily provide you with an estimate, including how much of your equity they are going to take from you.  If I recall correctly, I think that I have seen online sites that will generate these estimates.

Comment: Searching for "reverse mortgage calculator" gives about 6.6 million hits.  @Pete B: Why is it a bad deal, assuming the OP & spouse want to stay in the same house for the rest of their lives?

Comment: What is your planned lifespan?

Comment: @Pete B. yes, i understand that it's a bad deal.

Comment: "We have a loan of $300k with a mortgage payment of $1,786/month" Borrowing more money to service this existing debt just seems like utter insanity.

Comment: Reverse mortgages can be wonderful in the last few years of life as a way to stay in your house in your final illness and provide cash for your care. Taken too early, they eat up the value of the house in the way that interest is calculated and are a very bad deal.

Comment: @Harper - i have no idea.

Comment: @zeta-band how early would be too early?

Comment: @RayTayek - are you in an area (or willing to move to an area) where a $275-$300K home would be sufficient?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - i live in lakewood, a suburb of los angeles. so no way is there a house we can buy outright. i'm trying to compare maybe 60% of my equity by getting x$/month for  y years and then nothing until we both die or need to go into a nursing home vs getting all of my equity and relocating.

Comment: @zeta-band: How exactly does a reverse mortgage "eat up the value of the house"?  As I understand them, the lender pays you $X per month for the rest of your life (or you and spouse), then gets the house when you die.  It's fundamentally the same as an annuity: they're gambling that you (or rather the whole population of borrowers) die in accordance with actuarial expectations.  Sure, when you die, you lose the house, but what does that matter?

Comment: you don't get x$ forever, it will run out. also, interest gets added to the loan amount, so equity can go to zero.

Comment: @RayTayek - understood. I'd strongly suggest you look into the rules regarding nursing homes. With your income, you are not likely to get much (if any) Medicaid help.

Comment: @jamesqf - if I'm not mistaken, that's totally incorrect.  You're describing a sort of insurance thing. A reverse mortgage is nothing more than a mortgage (and the payment is just made out of the capital).  Note:  "I think" maybe it's different in the US or something.

Comment: @jamesqf The lender takes the interest on the money taken this year and adds it into the amount you owe that they calculate interest on next year. If you actually get the value of the house in payouts, you win. But if you die before it is all used up, the amount you get after the sale of the house minus the amount you owe is smaller than the amount you would have gotten had you not owed interest on the interest.

Comment: @RayTayek My mom started it 10 years before she deceased and that was much too early. I would only do it once there was some idea of when the end was.

Comment: @Ray Tayek: OK, maybe not "forever", but the term can be longer than your reasonable life expectancy.  (Unless you happen to be Jean Calment :-))  If you do wind up living longer than the mortgage term, you still get to live in the house while only paying taxes &c, just as if you owned it outright.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - we have some long term care insurance for 10 years.

Comment: @jamesqf  - that is my understanding also.

Comment: @Beanluc - how else to take advantage of our equity? maybe a heloc would be a reasonable choice? but that would force us to sell when we used it up.

Comment: @zeta-band: Re "But if you die before it is all used up, the amount you get...", I think one of us is missing something important here, which is that after you're dead, you're in no position to care about how much you get.  So the trade is realizing at least part of the equity in the home (and being free of mortgage payments) while you're still alive to enjoy it, versus dying with a major capital asset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can typically get up to 60% of the home value.  Here is decent article on what to expect.

[Reverse mortgage: What is it and how does it work?](https://www.bankrate.com/retirement/reverse-mortgage-what-is-it-and-how-does-it-work/)

It is your money and your equity, but I suggest that you do not get one.  They are a terrible instrument that you can quite easily outlive.

Comment: So since they have 50% equity, that means that they'd be able to get 10% ($60,000)?